# AZ CLI loop to download

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am looking for a method to loops through using specifically az cli, in order to download for example secrets/keys. I already have an ideea of what I am trying to achieve, but I would like to do it through az cli and I can't seem to understand how to loops through, like a for loop to go through all the keys/secrets and download them locally.
is there a way ? any sort of example would be useful. It must be in az cli.

Comment: you could always use powershell or bash. then get the data from az cli `az something list` then you should be able to iterate. you 're trying to iterate through key vault secrets ?

Comment: I am trying to setup a way to download all the keys from a keyvault for example. I got 10 keys, and I want to download all of them using az cli. I can do that manually or through a one line and replace the key that I want, but I would rather try to do it automatically. az keyvault secret backup  like using this command but automatically going through all the secrets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Powershell` or `Bash` you could always list all the secrets in a vault, iterate and backup.

Here is a Powershell sample:

```powershell
$keyVaultName = "<key vault name>"

# list secrets in a vault
$secrets = az keyvault secret list `
  --vault-name $keyVaultName `
| ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($secret in $secrets) {
  # backup each secret
  $filename = "$($secret.name).txt"
  az keyvault secret backup `
    --vault-name $keyVaultName `
    --name $secret.name `
    --file $filename
}
```

Comment: thank you for this.  so cool. i'll see how to do it in bash now. but this gave ma a couple of ideas! exactly what I was looking for! marked as the right answer in my opinion!